# Pnp.js Access to sub site

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-js

I use PnPJS within an REST API route like this:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("t").reserveListItemId().then(v => {
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("t").items.add({
        ID: v,
        Title: v.toString(),
    }).then(function (Data) {
    // codes
    });
})
```

but utilizing it this way, I can access the current site only.

How can I get access to a list item or create one in a list of a subsite?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, please try to use the following code to access subsite:

```
import { Web } from "@pnp/sp/webs";   
export interface IDataFromOtherScState {  
   listItems: any;  
}   
private web = Web("https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/subsite");   
public componentDidMount = () => {  
    this.web.lists.getByTitle("Employee").items().then((items) => {  
        this.setState({  
            listItems: items  
        });  
    }).catch((err) => {  
        console.log(err);  
    });  
}
```

More information for reference: [Use PnP JS To Fetch List Items From Other Site Collection In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-pnp-js-to-fetch-list-items-from-other-site-collection-in-sharepoint-online/)